# Understanding the nuances between collecting `flat_map` vs collecting `map` in rust

Tags: parsing, rust, functional-programming

I'm learning Rust using Advent of Code.
To resolve day 04 2021, I need to parse the following string:

```
88 67 20 19 15
22 76 86 44 73
 7 42  6 69 25
12 68 92 21 75
97 45 13 52 70

75 98 24 18 77
17 93 46 49 13
92 56 97 57 66
44  0 65 54 74
23  6 53 42 20

92 94  9 27 41
73 28 62 90 40
78  3 12 37 32
 8 86 91 16 30
84 38 68 11 19
```

Ideally, I would like to generate nested vectors `Vec<Vec<&str>>`.
My problem is that I don't understand why the following code doesn't work.

```rust
let bingo_sheet = grids_str
  split("\r\n\r\n")
  .map(|grid| grid.split_whitespace())
  .collect::<Vec<Vec<&str>>>();
```

I also don't understand the meaning behind cargo check. (Ok the trait doesn't exist. But why?)

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<Vec<&str>>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `SplitWhitespace<'_>`
  --> src\main.rs:36:10
   |
36 |         .collect::<Vec<Vec<&str>>>();
   |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<Vec<&str>>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=SplitWhitespace<'_>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<SplitWhitespace<'_>>` is not implemented for `Vec<Vec<&str>>`
```

After a bit of experimentation this usage of `flat_map` seems to work.

```rust
let bingo_sheet = grids_str
   .split("\r\n\r\n")
   .flat_map(|grid| grid.split_whitespace())
   .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
```

I don't understand what is happening here.
The `flat_map` code behaves as expected, but not the `map` code.

Comment: `.map(|grid| grid.split_whitespace().collect())` might work, `.map(|grid| grid.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>())` should work.

Comment: This is interesting @jmb. I'd like to understand your thought process. Why would I need to collect prematurely inside the map?

Comment: It's not "premature" - you collect the inner `Vec` inside the outer `map`, and collect the outer `Vec` afterwards. You need (at least) two `collect`s, if you want to collect two (layers of) `Vec`s.

Comment: @gberth because the `FromIterator` is implemented for `Vec<T>`, so you do need to collect it first. The `flat_map` versions works because you are just getting a single `Vec`

Comment: I recommend representing each board as a one-dimensional vector. It's much easier to work with overall, and also much more efficient. The only downside is that for indexing, you can't use `board[y][x]`, but need to use `board[5 * y + x]` instead. This downside is really minor in my opinion, in particular for this problem – you don't really need to index by `x` and `y` a lot.

Comment: @Netwave trentcl Thank you. This is exactly the type of information I was looking for.
I'm not sure why rust can't collect nested iterator though. I'm a C guy, so memory management with "functional-rust" is still unclear to me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Interesting idea Sven. Is `Vec<u8>` more efficient than `Vec<Vec<u8>>`  because of the memory layout? Or the lack of pointers? What about using arrays `[[u8; 5]; 5}` ?

Comment: A `Vec<Vec<u8>>` for a 5x5 board has 6 heap allocations and a bit of storage on the stack for the outer vector. Each element access needs two pointer indirection – first, following the outer point on the stack to the heap allocation containing the pointers to the individual rows, and then following the pointer to the right row. The memory layout of `[[u8; 5]; 5]` is contiguous on the stack, so it has zero pointer indirections and has the potential to be among the fastest approaches, but it's not very convenient to work with, since you can't easily collect into it.

Comment: My first comment was mostly about convenience. The performance aspects are just a side note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question has been answered briefly in the comments already while I wrote this but maybe a more detailed version still helps!

> I also don't understand the meaning behind cargo check. (Ok the trait doesn't exist. But why?)

The std provides conversions that are used often but it doesn't do all of them for you.

the call to `split_whitespace` returns a [`SplitWhitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitWhitespace.html) struct that implements (in the rest of this I will simply say "is") [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html).
the call to `map` returns a [`Map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html) struct which is an iterator over the return type of its given function, so it's an Iterator over an Iterator over string slices.

Because `Map` is an iterator, it has a [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method. As you can see in the docs, this method exists if there is a `B` that implements `FromIterator<Self::Item>`. This `B` is your `Vec<Vec<&str>>` and `Self::Item` is the item of `Map`, the `SplitWhiteSpace` struct. So `collect` is asking, "does `Vec<Vec<&str>>` implement `FromIterator<SplitWhiteSpace>`?, if yes, I exist, if not, I refuse to exist".

(`FromIterator<SplitWhiteSpace>` does not mean that `Vec<T>` can be made from the `SplitWhiteSpace` struct but that it can be made from some type `I` that is (or can be made into) an iterator over the item `SplitWhiteSpace`.)

So let's look into the Vec docs and find out if `Vec<Vec<&str>>` implements `FromIterator<SplitWhiteSpace>`. [`Vec` does implement `FromIterator<T>` but only for `Vec<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-FromIterator%3CT%3E), so in your case it implements `FromIterator<Vec<&str>>` but collect is asking it to implement `FromIterator<SplitWhiteSpace>`. It doesn't so your code doesn't compile.

In other words, when collecting a `Map<X>` into a `Vec<Y>`, X has to equal Y.

And this is why adding a `collect()` inside the `.map` works. Because that makes it a `Map<Vec<&str>>` which means the types match. `flatmap` also works because that creates a `FlatMap<&str>` which works similarly to `Map` and can be collected into a `Vec<&str>`. (`flat_map` does not need the `collect` inside its given function because it can handle iterators inside it)

Comment: Thanks, @Paul this is very useful.